# In Camel FTP component can take consumer.delay in minutes, where do I find the documentation on this

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am using Apache Camel 2.14.x, ftp component 2.14 as well

I can specify the consumer.delay option in milliseconds. 
However, I can see that some users have also used minutes i.e.

```
"consumer.delay=15m"  -- meaning 15 minutes,
```

Are there other units available such as seconds, hours, days, I searched  through the docs and can't find any mention of these units.

Can anyone please point me to the right docs. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for the ftp component

- http://camel.apache.org/ftp2

There is a box saying

> **More options**
>
> See File for more options as all the options from File is inherited.

So go and see the file component for more options

- http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

At the consumer options you can find the delay option.

As the ftp consumer is scheduled polling, then it has even more advanced options which is documented at the section *ScheduledPollConsumer Options* on this page:

- http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation for human friendly syntax:
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-specify-time-period-in-a-human-friendly-syntax.html

According to Claus Ibsen (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9930):

> All numeric values can be configured using that style.